# Dplyr warns: `...` is not empty

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

A new warning message appeared today when printing `tibbles`

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  head %>%
  as_tibble
```

prints

```
# A tibble: 6 x 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
3  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
4  21.4     6   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
5  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
6  18.1     6   225   105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
Warning message:
`...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `needs_dots`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?
```

How do I get rid of that warning?

this is my `sessionInfo()`

[image]

Comment: In my version of `dplyr/tibble` I am not getting the warning

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: thanks @r2evans -- change made as requested

Comment: This error seems to have been introduced in `pillar-1.4.5` (since I'm using 1.4.4 currently), see https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/798. I think your options are either (a) downgrade to 1.4.4 if you can; or (b) grab the github version of pillar to fix the bug. (And it looks like they are trying to expedite a CRAN release: https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/commit/a384b335ced735f957b08165de25f590d3520756#commitcomment-40507142)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This question is not a duplicate of any SO question (that I can find), but it's a duplicate of an issue on `tibble` ([tibble/#798](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/798)), where the reproducible code is merely:

```r
tibble::tibble(a = 1)
#> Warning: `...` is not empty.
#> 
#> We detected these problematic arguments:
#> * `needs_dots`
#> 
#> These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
#> Did you misspecify an argument?
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>       a
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
```

There is a patch in work ([a384b33](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/commit/a384b335ced735f957b08165de25f590d3520756)) and it appears they will push for a new CRAN release.

Your options are:

1. downgrade with

   ```r
   remotes::install_version("pillar", version = "1.4.4")
   ```
2. install the github version of `tibble`  with

   ```r
   remotes::install_github("tidyverse/tibble")
   ```
3. or wait for the CRAN release ([in work](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/commit/a384b335ced735f957b08165de25f590d3520756#commitcomment-40507142)).

Comment: This is resolved with tibble version 3.0.3 [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/tibble_3.0.3.zip)