# Error while ggploting variables of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tibble

I couldn't understand the error which is why I am not going to produce a `data.frame`. However, when I execute the following code

```
BY %>% select(c(1,3,4)) %>% 
+   pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value")
```

I get the following warning

```
# A tibble: 7,350 x 3
   Date       Variable Value
   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
 1 1993-03-01 Sim          0
 2 1993-03-01 Obs          0
 3 1993-03-02 Sim          0
 4 1993-03-02 Obs          0
 5 1993-03-03 Sim          0
 6 1993-03-03 Obs          0
 7 1993-03-04 Sim          0
 8 1993-03-04 Obs          0
 9 1993-03-05 Sim          0
10 1993-03-05 Obs          0
# ... with 7,340 more rows
Warning message:
`...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `needs_dots`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?
```

I believe there are some `characters` that are causing `warnings and errors`. Is there a way to find where exactly the values are `missing/replace by strange character` and how I can get rid of the entire `row` where I see them?

Comment: Where is the data to reproduce the issue? Why we can not see `ggplot` code if the question mentions `ggplot2`?

Comment: Thanks @Duck- I am going to write the data as `CSV` and then attached it here. If i produce a fake data here, i am not going to see the error. I actually tried the code on a random data and it worked fine.

Comment: Either upgrade to `tibble-3.0.3` or downgrade, this is a known issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62842388/3358272

Comment: Thank you @r2evans- the upgrading worked.